# Prolog cut operator behaviour

Tags: prolog, behavior, clause, prolog-cut

I have these clauses:

```
a(1).
a(2).
b(a).
c(A,B,C) :- a(A),d(B,C).
c(A,B,C) :- b(A),d(B,C).
d(B,C) :- a(B),!,a(C).
d(B,_) :- b(B).
```

When I run the query c(X,Y,Z) the answers are:

```
X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1 ;
X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 2 ;
X = 2, Y = 1, Z = 1 ;
X = 2, Y = 1, Z = 2 ;
X = a, Y = 1, Z = 1 ;
X = a, Y = 1, Z = 2.
```

So basically, the cut operator (in here d(B,C) :- a(B),!,a(C).) ignores the most recent choice points, i.e. it does not do a further search for d() and a(). I though that the cut ignores ALL previous choice points and won't do any backtracking.

Can someone explain the exact behavior and why am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some reading and the cut is working as follows:

```
1. Kills off the parent choice-point
2. Commits to all the choices made going through the rule
```

Thus :

```
1. d(B,_) :- b(B). is not explored
2. B in d(B,C) :- a(B),!,a(C). is irrevocably bound to 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I did not immediately understand your explanation of what the cut is doing, I looked at your code. My reading went roughly as follows:

- `c(A,B,C)` is true when:

  - `a(A)` and `d(B,C)`,
  - **or** `b(A)` and `d(B,C)`
- `d(B,C)` is true when `a(B)`, but only for the first `a(B)` you encounter, and don't look for any other `d(B,C)` definitions that you might find below this one.

My reading went like this because my interpretation of the cut is: commit to the choices made before encountering the cut within this predicate body, and discard clauses for this predicate below the clause containing the cut.

I hope this is at least remotely helpful.